# How to Modify MVC models to use nested Subcategories

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, view

I have a working MVC 5 app we use for classroom supplies with a simple welcome page that shows all categories along the left side of the page and a partial view that displays all subcategories for any category that is clicked.

Click any subcategory and the view updates with all products that match the subcategory.

It's worked fine for quite some time but now I need to add a third nested subcategory so my subcategories can have a subcategory nested below it like this:

(1)Category
   (2)---Subcategory
      (3)------Subcategory

or

(1)Art Supplies (catgory)
   (2)---Crayons (subcategory)
   (2)---Paper (subcategory)
      (3)------Construction (sub-subcategory)
      (3)------Plain (sub-subcategory)
      (3)------Etching (sub subcategory)

I can't get my models updated correctly to produce what I need. I can't work out the proper way to add that third nested subcateory to our models. I've spent a few days trying and just can't determine the correct way to do it.

I've tried a "flat" single model with parentID, Parent Category, but can't get the create and edit pages to display drop-downs like our models below produce.

Being able to utilize drop-down menus on our create and edit pages are a plus as we have young students who use the app and it's simpler for them.

And I'd like to use the same to update our public view.

I know if I get the models correct then I can translate that to my views as needed. If anyone can help with the proper structure it would be very much appreciated.

Below are our models:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class SubCategory
{
    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }


    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int ProductNumber { get; set; }
    public string UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Here is our controller for our create action:

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    private EFDbContext db = new EFDbContext();
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var catid = 1;
        try
        {
            catid = (from c in db.Categories select c).FirstOrDefault().CategoryId;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            catid = 1;
        }
        ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryId", "CategoryName", catid);
        var subcategories = (from sub in db.SubCategories where sub.CategoryId == catid select new { sub.SubCategoryId, sub.SubCategoryName }).ToList();
        ViewBag.SubCategoryId = new SelectList(subcategories, "SubCategoryId", "SubCategoryName");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Products/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ProductId,ProductName,ProductNumber,UnitOfMeasure,ProductDescription,Price,CategoryId,SubCategoryId")] Product product)
    {
        var subcatcheck = (from sub in db.SubCategories where sub.CategoryId == product.CategoryId && sub.SubCategoryId == product.SubCategoryId select new { sub.SubCategoryId, sub.SubCategoryName }).ToList();
        if (ModelState.IsValid && product.ProductName != null && product.CategoryId != 0 && product.SubCategoryId != 0 && subcatcheck.Count != 0)
        {
            db.Products.Add(product);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryId", "CategoryName", product.CategoryId);
        //ViewBag.SubCategoryId = new SelectList(db.SubCategories, "SubCategoryId", "SubCategoryName", product.SubCategoryId);
        var subcategories = (from sub in db.SubCategories where sub.CategoryId == product.CategoryId select new { sub.SubCategoryId, sub.SubCategoryName }).ToList();
        ViewBag.SubCategoryId = new SelectList(subcategories, "SubCategoryId", "SubCategoryName");
        return View(product);
    }
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

And lastly our create view
    @model 3rd6thgrade.Domain.Entities.Product

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>



@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Product</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UnitOfMeasure, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UnitOfMeasure, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UnitOfMeasure, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, "CategoryId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @*@Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })*@
            @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null, new {onchange = "this.form.submit(0)", @class = "form-control"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubCategoryId, "SubCategoryId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownList("SubCategoryId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    @*  @Html.DropDownList("SubCategoryId", null, new { onchange = "this.form.submit(0)", @class = "form-control" })*@
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubCategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: For a start your `Category` model should be a hierarchical model so that you can use as many nested levels as you want - `public class Category { public int ID { get; set; } public string Name { get; set; } public List<Category> SubCategories { get; set; } }` so that you can display a hierarchical menu structure.

Comment: Thank you Steven.  I've updated my category Model to this: `public class Category {public int CategoryId { get; set; }public string CategoryName { get; set; } public List<Category> SubCategories { get; set; } public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }}` but after the migration and re-scaffolding, there is no scaffolded item in the create page to assign a subcategory.  Is that even possible with Entity framework or do I need to assign new subcategories as code first only?